# "taxwise," "tax wise," or "tax-wise"

Tags: word-usage, orthography, colloquialisms

What should be the correct spelling for "-wise" combinations in **adverbial** coinages like "sportswise," "weatherwise," "businesswise, "saleswise," "taxwise," etc.?

Should it be "NOUN wise," "NOUN-wise," or "NOUNwise"?

I'd instinctively go with the "NOUNwise" spelling but my spellchecker says it's wrong and suggests both "NOUN wise" and "NOUN-wise" as alternatives.

> **wise**
>
> A suffixal use of *wise* in adverbs denoting manner, position, direction, reference, etc.: *clockwise*; *edgewise*; *marketwise*; *timewise*.
>
> usage: The suffix *-wise* is old in the language in adverbs referring to manner, direction, etc.: *crosswise*; *lengthwise*. Coinages like *marketwise*, *saleswise*, and *weatherwise* are often criticized, perhaps because of their association with the news and entertainment media: *Moneywise, as they were already saying in the motion-picture industry, Hollywood was at its peak*. This suffix should not be confused with the adjective *wise*, which appears in such compounds as *streetwise* and *worldly-wise*.
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://forum.figu.org/cgi-bin/us/board-admin.cgi?action=quick&do=print&HTTP_REFERER=12/12773&postindex=65514)

Comment: I can't cite any authoritative reference for this matter, but since this suffix is considered informal and people attach it to very different kinds of nouns (experience-wise, imagination-wise, ...) I think there should be a gap in between to denote that it's a deliberate addition and not a part of the word. And a 'space' gap is not a good idea too, because no suffix is written apart from the main word, and it might also be mistaken for the adjective _wise_.

Comment: You may have checked already, but no harm in quoting this (note the hyphenation): [-wise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-wise): _informal_ With respect to; concerning: _security-wise, there are few problems._ **Usage:** In modern English the suffix -wise is attached to nouns to form a sentence adverb meaning ‘concerning or with respect to’, as in confidence-wise, tax-wise, price-wise, time-wise, news-wise, and culture-wise. The suffix is very productive and widely used in modern English but most of the words so formed are considered inelegant or not good English style.

Comment: @Elian You didn't bother to check in a dictionary for the actual words, did you? I found "moneywise" and "timewise" straight away in the on-line Oxford.

Comment: @BillJ "moneywise" and "timewise" are given here as mere examples to support my question. Even though these are spelled in one word in the ODO, they still are not recognized by my spellchecker when I type them in one word...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [here](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/hyphen.html):

> Two or more words that collectively act as an adjective should be hyphenated when they appear immediately before the noun they modify. This helps prevent misreading.

I know this had to be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: But "money-wise" doesn't appear before the noun it modifies. A better section to quote from the same page would be "Hyphenated compounds use hyphens between the words: eye-opener, check-in, free-for-all"

Comment: @Yay :  Exact usage or an example in a sentence hasn't been specified by the OP. So, I guess, it can be one of the possible cases.

Comment: I can't think of a single case where *NOUN-wise* works as an adjective. Except for a couple of collocations, the prefix *-wise* creates adverbs (see the second comment above), not adjectives that can appear immediately before a noun.

Comment: I think the quote is more of a suggestion and not a _rule_. Adjective might be one of the cases for hyphenation. Why should it mean that it is not applicable for adverbs?

Comment: @thokiro I just made an edit to clarify. It's actually he adverbial usage I'm interested in. Thanks for your answer anyway. :-)